# python project runs different in two devices

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

I have a python project that crawls some *.txt files and brings some words from each *.txt file in a new file.
This project runs well in my first device, and output is a .txt file that has correct content; but in my second device, it runs and there is no error, but it creates an empty .txt file.
python versions are the same. both have windows 10.

here is the code:

```
import re

#pattern to find
pattern_name_start=r'id="p-name">'
pattern_name_end=r'</div>'

crawlfile=open("product-name.txt","w")


for j in range(10):
    #creating file locations and assigning it to $address
    address="pages/{0}.txt".format(j)

    #opening webpage file which is saved in .txt format and reading its content
    pagesfile=open(address,"r")
    pagetext=pagesfile.read()

    #establishing first character location of the iran-code and generating gs1 code and writing it in the file
    pn=""
    product_name=""
    matchname=re.search(pattern_name_start,pagetext)
    if matchname:
        strtchar=matchname.start()

        #49 is the number of id="p-name characters + number of spaces
        for i in range (49,350):
            pn=pn+pagetext[strtchar+i]

        matchnameend=re.search(pattern_name_end,pn)

        if matchnameend:
            endchar=matchnameend.start()

        #32 is the number of spaces
        for i in range(endchar-33):
            product_name=product_name+pn[i]

        crawlfile.write(product_name+ '\n')

    pagesfile.close()

crawlfile.close()
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can do no more than make random guesses as to the problem. We don't have access to your machines or the files that you are running the code on. The most likely explanation is that there is some difference in the files that you are running the code on.

Comment: Try checking whether the path is present in the new system as well.